# xgboost error - label must be in [0,1] when my label is already in numeric and I need result in numbers not in range of 0 ,1

Tags: r, label, regression, data-science, xgboost

I m using `xgboost` for regression  problem but I m getting error regarding response variable which  is output sales and it is initially numeric in class but as I  use xgboost it shows error BUT I want output in numeric form only

```
labels <- train$Item_Outlet_Sales# train label
ts_label <- test$Item_Outlet_Sales  # test label

# converted into matrix ( one hot encoding )
new_tr <- model.matrix(~.+0,data = train[,-c("Item_Outlet_Sales"),with=F])
new_ts <- model.matrix(~.+0,data = test[,-c("Item_Outlet_Sales"),with=F])

## checking class
class(labels)
[1] "numeric"
```

I have created label or response variable in test as 
 `test$Item_Outlet_Sales <- NA`

```
class(test$Item_Outlet_Sales)
[1] "logical"

# coverting `ts_label` into numeric as it initially is logical
ts_label <- as.numeric(ts_label)-1
class(ts_label)
[1] "numeric"
```

now

```
 dtrain1 <- xgb.DMatrix(data = new_tr,label = labels) 
 dtest1 <- xgb.DMatrix(data = new_ts,label= ts_label)

 xgbmodel1 = xgb.train(data=dtrain1, nround=150, max_depth=5, eta=0.1,  subsample=0.9, 
                       objective="reg:logistic", booster="gbtree", eval_metric="rmse")
```

Error -

```
Error in xgb.iter.update(bst$handle, dtrain, iteration - 1, obj) : 
  [14:08:41] amalgamation/../src/objective/regression_obj.cc:108: 
  label must be in [0,1] for logistic regression
```

I used then this:

```
xgbmodel1 = xgb.train(data=dtrain1, nround=150, max_depth=5, eta=0.1,  subsample=0.9, 
                      objective="reg:linear", booster="gbtree", eval_metric="rmse")
```

I got all values of response variable  equal to -1 and my rmse score is infinite..

Please tell me how to implement `xgboost` effectively in this case even with default conditions so no error comes.

I have 4 categorical variables in this dataset.

here is a subset of train dataset

sure, r <- train[1:3,]

r

Item_Identifier Item_Fat_Content   Item_Type Item_MRP Outlet_Identifier
1:           FDA15          Low Fat       Dairy 249.8092            OUT049
2:           DRC01          Regular Soft Drinks  48.2692            OUT018
3:           FDN15          Low Fat        Meat 141.6180            OUT049
   Outlet_Establishment_Year Outlet_Location_Type       Outlet_Type Item_Outlet_Sales
1:                      1999               Tier 1 Supermarket Type1         3735.1380
2:                      2009               Tier 3 Supermarket Type2          443.4228
3:                      1999               Tier 1 Supermarket Type1         2097.2700
   Item_Weight Item_Visibility Outlet_Size
1:        9.30      0.01604730           2
2:        5.92      0.01927822           2
3:       17.50      0.01676007           2

Answer (score 3):

I see two problems here:

1. The algorithm expects labels to be either 0s or 1s. On the contrary your code sets them to the value 0 or -1. Correct the line where you define the `ts_label` variable as follows:

   ```
   ts_label <- as.numeric(ts_label)
   ```
2. You have a binary target and categorical predictors. Why do you want to do logistic regression? I feel "binary:logistic" may be a better objective here. "reg:linear" makes no sense and your loss function should be based on accuracy and not rmse.

Comment: i dont have binary target , it a regression problem and i have to tell the total output sales for each item but this i m applying xgboost first time to increase accuracy. Please tell me as to how make changes to implement for regression .

Comment: This is a practice  problem and metric used for evaluation is rmse and so i wanted to set it according to it so could know what effect parameter tuning can have

Comment: I mean, you mentioned that your "label" variable is logical, which means TRUE and FALSE. I don't see how that can be used for regression.

Comment: at the top i am mentioning the error that it is asking for label to be 0 and 1.and I only added an response column to test data as it was not there by test$Item_Output_Sales <- NA.....i think error is with one hot encoding lines as there is not enough examples to apply for regression.

Comment: can you share your data or a part of it?

Comment: sure, r <- train[1:3,]